# tailwind build task throws tailwind: command not found

Tags: npm, task, package.json

I tried to run a build task, I've used this task before a lot of times, worked just fine. Than magically it's just not working anymore.

Here is the build task : `"build:css": "tailwind build style.css -o public/style.css"`

[image]

Here is the content of the package.json

```html
{
  "name": "doksi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build:css": "tailwind build style.css -o public/style.css"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "tippy.js": "^6.2.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Any of you had some similar problems?
Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. Watch [this video from Adam Wathan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL7CcGwsqRpSM3w9BT_21tUU8JN2SnyckR&v=21HuwjmuS7A&index=1) (creator of tailwindcss),
and follow the instructions.

I suggest you remove the `node_modules` directory and also remove `tailwindcss` (and possibly `tailwind`) from the dependencies of your `package.json` file. And since you deleted `node_modules` directory, run `npm install` to install remaining listed dependencies in `package.json` file)